Anti-siphon spigot dripping from unique downward-facing port
Dripping anti-siphon spigot with unique design
Hi all - I recently bought a house and noticed a slow drip coming from the spigot in the back yard. The spigot appears to be a discontinued Arrowhead Apache 455, which has a little 1/8” diameter downward-facing blowoff port through which water briefly gets ejected when the anti-siphon device is functioning when you turn the faucet on/off (no water gushes from under the cap, only through this little port). So understandably, this little port drips for a bit after you turn it off… but it shouldn’t be dripping days later, which I am finding is the case.
I don’t see any spigots or hose bibs available today with this little downward-facing blowoff port. It struck me as fairly unique, and sure enough - nobody makes em like this anymore.
If this was a standard design, I’d be comfortable following the many online articles and YouTube videos for how to adjust or fix, but given the unique design, I’m proceeding with caution before I try to take anything apart. Is there anything special about this little port? Am I overthinking this, or is there a DIY-able fix for this?

There are a few washers/o-rings shown in the exploded part diagram:

If the drip never stops, there must be water getting past the valve. Item 6, the o-ring located at the end of the stem looks to be the main seal. Remove the handle and then the stem and take the o-ring to a local hardware store and see if you can find a matching one.
If you cannot find a matching one, you can order the replacement Stem Rebuild Kit PK1000.
If the drip eventually stops but takes a long time, it could be residual water left inside the valve taking a long time to drain, especially if the valve is not sloped down towards the drain port.
Refer to the image on page 3 of the manufacturer's documentation shown here.
If the drip occurs while in use, it would be the washer noted as item 12.
If you cannot find a matching one, you may be able to order the replacement part PK1440 however the manufacture says they no longer make it.
I have no affiliation with that site, it was the first site I found with those parts.

Thank you for looking into this and recommending a fix - I really appreciate it! I'll give that a shot this weekend and report back.

I'm going to revise my answer, as I think the more likely item to check is the o-ring at item 6.

That makes sense - the more I thought about this, the more it seemed like the dripping should eventually dry up unless the valve stem wasn’t getting a good seal when closed. I’ll start there and check things out. Really appreciate your help!!

I have two of these same faucets also and if you order the part at: https://www.chicagofaucetshoppe.com/product-p/arw-pk1440.htm
It will fit and all, but it does NOT appear to look like the original Arrowhead part and will come in plain packaging with no markings of Arrowhead. Water will NOT come out of the this drain when you turn the water off for a few seconds like the original so I think this works differently. Maybe water comes out of it when the pressure builds from freezing or something.

Thanks! Mine decided to stop dripping, or at least it’s more of an intermittent drip, so I’m keeping a close eye on it but I picked up a PK1000 stem rebuild kit to have on hand just in case.
Helpful hint for anyone in the Seattle area - McLendon’s sells the PK1000.
